# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined on Ionic 4 , Angular 8

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, inappbrowser, ionic-native

I'm using `Ionic 4` and `Angular 8` for my project.
My project needs to integrate with a payment gateway service.
I'm using [Ionic 4 InAppBrowser plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) to open payment gateway site.

This is my implementation:

```
const browserRef = this.browser.create(paymentUrl, '_blank');
this._hookBrowserClosedSubscription = browserRef.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

I use command `ionic cordova run android --device --livereload --no-native-run` to run my app on a real device. I got the following error when I tried opening a page using InAppBrowser plugin:

**Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined**

I have been searching for this error, mostly they mention about its existence on **browser**, not **real devices**.

The packages I'm using:

```
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0"
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.8.0",
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank

Comment: I couldn't figure it out enough to write an answer but I'm suspecting that the `loaderror` is happening before `loadstop` so there is nothing to subscribe to. Perhaps [looking at some other peoples code](https://github.com/search?q=.on%28%27loaderror%27%29.subscribe&type=Code) will help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally,

I found the issue's root cause.
I don't know why but `in-app-browser` appears in my `packages.json`:

```
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0"
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.8.0",
```

When I ran my application on my device, using `Chrome Inspect`, I saw a warning message:

**Native: InAppBrowser is not installed or you are running on a browser. Falling back to window.open, all instance methods will NOT work.**

I tried to install in-app-browser by using 2 commands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

When I ran my app again, the warning message disappeared and the browser worked as my expectation.

What a silly mistake.

Hope this helps someone who has the same situation.